# CakePHP Format Value in View

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a custom PHP function that I have made which returns a formatted date based on when the date is.
Called: formatDate($date)

In my controller I use something like -

```
$this->set('examples',$this->Example->find('all'))
```

Then in my view I have a foreach like:

```
echo $examples['Example']['date']
```

What I want to do is in my view be able to call:

```
echo formatDate($examples['Example']['date'])
```

Currently I have the function at the bottom of my view.ctp page but I think there must be a better alternative

Comment: Write that function in Model , and in view call like $this->MODEL_NAME->formatDate();

Comment: Could you post your date method? It may be that the Time helper may already do this for you. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html

A helper would be the best place to write functions for a view if they're needed in the view only.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird In CakePHPs 1/2.x MVC implementation, models are not supposed to be accessed by views, not to mention that trying to do so will result in an error as there are by default no model references on a view class.

Comment: @ndm ok then IT can be called by Controller and then passed to view

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird It could, but it shouldn't. It's not a controllers [**concern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) how specific values are being formatted in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom helper, and associated function therein. then you can call it from a view as and when you need it

```
<?php echo $this->MyHelper->MyFunction($date); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple approaches to what you are looking for.
One would be to call a controller function (inside your view) with requestAction.

```
echo $this->requestAction('controllerName/actionName/'.$parameter);
```

or

```
echo $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'controllerName', 'action' => 'actionName'), array('date' => unformattedDate));
```

Where /controllerName/actionName will handle the date format.

Comment: -1 That is horribly inefficient, as mentioned by @HelloSpeakman in the comments, helpers are the way to go.